# Alert box that pops up at certain time on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript and I made it so that it records the number on the getTime() method, and it will add a certain number of milliseconds to that. Then I want an alert box to pop up once the new number of milliseconds has passed since January 1, 1970 at midnight.

I am pretty new at programming, so it would be helpful if you could explain how it works too.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share your code so far, please?

Comment: What have you tried?  Post code.  We aren't here to do it for you.  No matter what, you'll need some combination of `Date()` and `setTimeout()` Also, I would suggest against using a popup, place the text into something on the HTML page itself so it isn't as annoying.

Comment: It's a long story, but I need to use a popup. I'm pretty new at programming, like I mentioned earlier, so I don't know what setTimeout() is.

Comment: Also, do you mean a popup or an alert box?

Comment: I meant alert, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) starts a process that will call a function asynchronously every `x` number of milliseconds.  [`Date()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) gets the current time and date.  Also, I added another little bit to make it where

**Edit 1**

In `HTML/JavaScript` you can either embed the JavaScript in the webpage or in a separate script that is interpreted during the page load.  Here, we are just going to embed it in the HTML for brevity.

With respect to your question (If I'm understanding correctly), you want to be able to record what time it is and then tell how long it has been since then.  In the `<script>` tag, we have a global variable `startTime` that gets set to the epoch of the program being run.  `Date()` gets what time it is.  `main()` is what gets run after our page gets loaded so the very first thing to happen is `startTime` gets set to the current time with `Date()` and another special function `setTimeout()` gets started.

`setTimeout()` takes two parameters, a function reference and a duration.  After being called, it schedules for the function it was given to be fired after a duration has passed.  In our case, we tell it to fire `getTimePassage()` after `5000` milliseconds.

What `getTimePassage()` does is gets the current time again, through `Date()` and then stores *that* time in `currDate`.  Then we store the difference between the two in `timeDiff` with the call `var timeDiff = (currDate - startTime);`  After that, it's a piece of cake to output the answer to whatever format you want whether it be a `<div>`, the console, an alert, or a popup.  Here we do all of them.

The last important thing is how we **reschedule** `getTimePassage()` again using `setTimeout()`  This makes it so that we keep updating how much time has passed during our run.

**Edit 2**

> but what would I do to start and stop the timer?

I've added two buttons to the page that will start and stop the timer.  You need to add a flag, `shouldRestartTimer` which will tell the function to not continue remaking the timer.  Additionally, I've refactored main and separated the start logic into `startGetTimePassage()` and `stopGetTimePassage()` which start and stop the timer respectively.  At the program start, `main()` sets the start time and fires off the `startGetTimePassage()`.

Additionally, I've added 2 buttons and 4 check boxes to the HTML page that will let you select where your time gets displayed as well as allow you to stop and start your timer.  When the page loads, it's still started, but now you can start it up again after stopping.  I would recommend as an exercise you try to fix the bug that follows with this: If the timer is already running, and you press `start` several setTimeouts() are ignited which will all send time to the selected output and pressing `stop` won't fix this.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Timer</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script>
         // I'm the time of the start of this program
         var startTime;

         // I'm a global variable that holds a handle to the setTimout() object
         var timer;

         // I say whether or not we should keep ticking
         var shouldRestartTimer = true;

         // I get the current time and subtract it from the start time
         function getTimePassage() {
            // I'm the div that is going to print the answer
            var timeDiv = document.getElementById("time");

            // I'm the current time
            var currDate = new Date();

            // I determine how much time has passed
            var timeDiff = (currDate - startTime);

            // I'm the answer to get printed
            var timeString = "Time Passed: " + timeDiff;

            // I put the anser into the HTML after subtracting 
            // the start time from the current time
            if (document.getElementById("shouldDiv").checked) {
               timeDiv.innerHTML = timeString;
            }

            // If I were uncommented I would spawn an alert box
            if (document.getElementById("shouldAlert").checked) {
               alert(timeString);
            }

            // I'm a popup that does what you expect
            if (document.getElementById("shouldPopup").checked) {
               var timeWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=200");
               timeWindow.document.write(timeString);
            }

            // I'm going to tell the same thing to console
            if (document.getElementById("shouldConsole").checked) {
               console.log(timeString);
            }

            // I start this all over again
            timer = setTimeout(getTimePassage, 5000);
         }

         function startGetTimePassage() {
            shouldRestartTimer = true;

            // I make a timer that will run "getTimePassage" every 5000 millis
            timer = setTimeout(getTimePassage, 5000);
         }

         // I stop the timout
         function stopGetTimePassage() {
            shouldRestartTimer = false;
            clearTimeout(timer);
         }

         // I get everything ready
         function main() {
            // I'm setting the time that this all began
            startTime = new Date();

            // I start the timer and tell it to repeat            
            startGetTimePassage();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <!--I start the whole process-->
   <body onload="main();">
      <!--I'm a div that is going to store text to not be irritating-->
      <div id="time">Time</div>

      <!--I'm a check box that will make the time go to an alert-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="shouldAlert">Alert<br>
      <!--I'm a pre-selected check box that will make the time go to the div above-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="shouldDiv" checked>Div<br>
      <!--I'm a check box that will make the time to a separate pop-up window-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="shouldPopup">Pop-up<br>
      <!--I'm a check box that will make the time go to the console-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="shouldConsole">Console<br>

      <!--I'm a button to start the timer if you stop it-->
      <button onclick="startGetTimePassage();">Start</button>
      <!--I'm a button to stop a timer after it's started-->
      <button onclick="stopGetTimePassage();">Stop</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't exactly get what this is doing, even with the comments, so could you explain it a little bit more, please? It would really help.

Comment: Sure, check my edits.  Let me know if you still need more explaining.

Comment: Oh, sorry I made you go through all of that, but I actually have the user typing in a number, which I will transform to milliseconds, and then the alert box will pop up that many milliseconds after they push OK on a confirm box. Sorry you had to do all of that for almost nothing. I also don't need the HTML part of it, I already have that covered.

Comment: Oh, never mind. You did get it right, but it still is a little confusing. I get that I am supposed to replace the number 5000 with whatever variable has the number of milliseconds that I want, but what would I do to start and stop the timer?

Comment: I've added a way to start and stop the timer, check my `Edit 2` and see the code that follows.